# Create Formula with Array for Data Reorganization

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have some jumbled-up data I was supplied by another person on my team, as in, the type of data in the different columns does not line up row-to-row (example on 'Raw Data' tab in spreadsheet below). However, the contents of each cell do list what column they *should* be in, and I want to create a formula to properly organize the data to show up how it actually should, but with an arrayformula setup so it only needs to be applied to the top cell in the column. I was able to get a formula working to do so in a singular cell, but due to the amount of data I have to work with, I'd rather have an array that works across an entire column, rather than a single cell at a time.

Here's a sheet with some sample data to look at:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/131MjDrhHEpZKQHXjOQXHlfbBFsm2sb7YfvXqXS0LUtc/edit#gid=2099735833

Here's the formula I created that works for a single cell (It's also in cell B2 in the Clean Data tab). Unfortunately, indirect() doesn't work with arrays, and I can't think of another way to have it look up the relevant information. Is this possible to do? Or is there another way altogether to get the end result I'm after? Open to most anything, though I'd prefer not to have to install any scripts.

```
=hlookup(
        "*"&B$1&"*",
        indirect(
                "Raw Data!"
                &
                match(
                        vlookup(
                                "*"&$A2&"*",
                                'Raw Data'!$A:$E,
                                1,
                                FALSE
                        ),
                        'Raw Data'!$A:$A,
                        0
                )
                &
                ":"
                &
                match(
                        vlookup(
                                "*"&$A2&"*",
                                'Raw Data'!$A:$E,
                                1,
                                FALSE
                        ),
                        'Raw Data'!$A:$A,
                        0
                )
        ),
        1,
        FALSE
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a complex problem, but I can offer a solution in a single Cell. Try this in `Clean Data!A1` (deleting all other cell data on the sheet):

```
=arrayformula({"Address","Zip Code","Bedrooms","Architectural Style","Property Type","Sewage Type";query(split(regexreplace(if(regexmatch(if(regexmatch(regexreplace(regexreplace(trim(flatten(query(transpose(regexreplace(regexreplace(regexreplace('Raw Data'!A:E," ",char(9998)),"<strong>|<span>|</span>",),"</strong>"&char(10),char(9998))),"",9^9)))," ",char(9999)),char(9998)," "),"Bedrooms: "),regexreplace(regexreplace(trim(flatten(query(transpose(regexreplace(regexreplace(regexreplace('Raw Data'!A:E," ",char(9998)),"<strong>|<span>|</span>",),"</strong>"&char(10),char(9998))),"",9^9)))," ",char(9999)),char(9998)," "),regexreplace(regexreplace(regexreplace(trim(flatten(query(transpose(regexreplace(regexreplace(regexreplace('Raw Data'!A:E," ",char(9998)),"<strong>|<span>|</span>",),"</strong>"&char(10),char(9998))),"",9^9)))," ",char(9999)),char(9998)," "),"(Architectural Style)",char(9999)&"$1")),"Architectural Style"),if(regexmatch(regexreplace(regexreplace(trim(flatten(query(transpose(regexreplace(regexreplace(regexreplace('Raw Data'!A:E," ",char(9998)),"<strong>|<span>|</span>",),"</strong>"&char(10),char(9998))),"",9^9)))," ",char(9999)),char(9998)," "),"Bedrooms: "),regexreplace(regexreplace(trim(flatten(query(transpose(regexreplace(regexreplace(regexreplace('Raw Data'!A:E," ",char(9998)),"<strong>|<span>|</span>",),"</strong>"&char(10),char(9998))),"",9^9)))," ",char(9999)),char(9998)," "),regexreplace(regexreplace(regexreplace(trim(flatten(query(transpose(regexreplace(regexreplace(regexreplace('Raw Data'!A:E," ",char(9998)),"<strong>|<span>|</span>",),"</strong>"&char(10),char(9998))),"",9^9)))," ",char(9999)),char(9998)," "),"(Architectural Style)",char(9999)&"$1")),regexreplace(if(regexmatch(regexreplace(regexreplace(trim(flatten(query(transpose(regexreplace(regexreplace(regexreplace('Raw Data'!A:E," ",char(9998)),"<strong>|<span>|</span>",),"</strong>"&char(10),char(9998))),"",9^9)))," ",char(9999)),char(9998)," "),"Bedrooms: "),regexreplace(regexreplace(trim(flatten(query(transpose(regexreplace(regexreplace(regexreplace('Raw Data'!A:E," ",char(9998)),"<strong>|<span>|</span>",),"</strong>"&char(10),char(9998))),"",9^9)))," ",char(9999)),char(9998)," "),regexreplace(regexreplace(regexreplace(trim(flatten(query(transpose(regexreplace(regexreplace(regexreplace('Raw Data'!A:E," ",char(9998)),"<strong>|<span>|</span>",),"</strong>"&char(10),char(9998))),"",9^9)))," ",char(9999)),char(9998)," "),"(Architectural Style)",char(9999)&"$1")),"(Property Type)",char(9999)&"$1")),"Address:\ ?|Zip Code:\ ?|Bedrooms:\ ?|Architectural Style\ ?|Property Type\ ?|Sewage Type\ ?",),char(9999),1,0),"where Col2 is not null",0)})
```

[image]